# Cannot set DIV background to an image. Using Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel

The link to the image should be relative to the css file but it does not seem to be working, there is no background using this. I've even tired adding the image in the same folder as the css file and that does not work either.

**CSS**

```
#header {
    padding:10px;
    color: white;
    background: url('../../resources/assets/images/background1.png');
    height: 350px;  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav">
        <p>Nav Bar</p>
    </div>

    <p>Test</p>

</div>
```

**File Structure**
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uloc.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `resources` directory is out of your `public` directory. Images shouldn't be stored there.

You could place them in `storage` and create a symbiotic link with `php artisan storage:link`.

However, in your case, you should just place them in `public/assets/images` for your purposes.

Otherwise, utilize something like an S3 bucket or another CDN provider.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your background image path at first & after that you can check with using different image in css.

1. For an example please check your code by various steps-

   ## header {float:left; width:300px; height:350px; background:url('../../resources/assets/images/images.jpg');}

Note: Please check your image extension & you can use a different image to check your correction

2. Many times in html& css missing Div & Brackets creates problem to show your css & code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a private image, you should put them inside /public directory. It is the root directory in Laravel app. So when you get image from css or elsewhere, you should know that the root is public folder. /images/background1.jpg means it is in images folder inside public folder in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It should work I have tried the same thing based on your structure.
It is working for me
Please make sure you have refereed CSS file properly
[image]